# Scope comparing two counts not returning anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, scope

Rails 4 Postgres 9.something

Model has_many operand_1 and operand_2

I want a scope that returns all the models with more operand_1 than 2, but it's returning empty every time. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 scope :comparison, -> operand_1, operand_2 {
   joins(operand_1.to_sym).
   joins(operand_2.to_sym).
   select('model_name.id').
   group('model_name.id').
   having("count(#{operand_1}.id) > count(#{operand_2}.id)")
 }
```

end

PS. I know that this is a PSQL injection risk, Have validations for days : P

Comment: The Joins are working perfectly, although the .to_sym is redundant

Comment: Check your logs to see the sql, you may be able to work from there.

Comment: A good way to debug something like this is to take @Swards approach and look at the sql. The `to_sql` method provided by `ActiveRecord::Base` can be very helpful, so you end up with your debugging like: `ModelName.comparison(o1, o2).to_sql`

Comment: Do you have any errors / feedback? Looks okay to me